# TF Keras ValueError: Shapes (None, 3, 3) and (None, 3) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

When running my LSTM model, in which I want to take an input (x,y) and output a sequence `[(x1,y1), (x2, y2)..., (x,y)]` I get a `ValueError`.

I've read other problems like this, but I still am unable to grasp how I'd fix my model, although I know what the problem is.

My model:

```
def lstm_functional(X, Y):
    # Input, LSTM and output layers using the functional API
    inputs = keras.Input(shape = (2,1)) 
    # 2,1=X.shape[1],X.shape[2] (timesteps and features)
    lstm = layers.LSTM(64, activation=activation, return_sequences = True)(inputs)
    outputs = layers.LSTM(3, activation=activation)(lstm) # 3=X.shape[0], samples

    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, name="model_functional")
    model.compile(
        loss="categorical_crossentropy",
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),
        metrics=["accuracy"]
    )
    model.fit(X, Y, batch_size=2, epochs=2)
    return model

if __name__ == "__main__":

    model = lstm_functional(X, Y)
```

To simplify the problem I created an input (`X`) and output (`Y`) which I use to test my model.

My input and output data:

```
X = np.array([(i, i*2) for i in range(1,4)]) 
Y = np.array([[(i, i*2, i*3)]*i for i in range(1,4)])
print(X)
# [(1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 6)]
print(Y)
# [[(1, 2, 3)], [(2, 4, 6), (2, 4, 6)], [(3, 6, 9), (3, 6, 9), (3, 6, 9)]]

Y = np.array(Y)
X = np.array(X)
X = X.reshape(X.shape + (1,))
print(X.shape)
# (3, 2, 1)
```

In the data my X values are always a tuple of length 2, but the length of my Y value varies: a list with a varying amount of tuples of length 3.

In the code above I also convert X and Y to a numpy arrays and reshape X, as an LSTM takes in three-dimensional input.

If I try to run my code at this point I'll get an error:

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

I assume the reason for this is that the output data (`Y`) is not of uniform length. Is there a way to use output data of varying length?

What I did was pad my `Y` sequence to make it uniform:

```
Y = pad_sequences(Y, maxlen = max(len(i) for i in Y), padding = "post", value = (0,0,0))
print(Y.shape)
# (3, 3, 3)
```

And now I run the model again, but I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 3, 3) and (None, 3) are incompatible
```

The problem is the final output layer: the output from the output layer `(None, 3)` does not match with the given `Y` shape `(None, 3,3)`. None stands for the batch size, which can be altered and is not static, therefore None. How can I reshape/modify/process the `Y` data so it fits the output of the model?

Just for clarification I'll add the summary of my model:

```
model.summary()
Model: "model_functional"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 2, 1)]            0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm (LSTM)                  (None, 2, 64)             16896     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 3)                 816       
=================================================================
Total params: 17,712
Trainable params: 17,712
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
```

I could fix the problem by flattening the individual samples in Y as well as changing the model's output to 9:

```
Y = Y.reshape((Y.shape[0], Y.shape[1]*Y.shape[0])) # shape (3,9)
```

But in this case I lose the tuples in the list, which I want to keep, as every tuple corresponds to a step in the sequence.

**Questions**

1. Is there a way to use output data (`Y`) that is not of uniform length?
2. How can I fit the `Y` data to the model, so that the individual tuples in the `Y` sequence remain, meaning that when i use model.predict(X,Y) I will get a list of tuples where the tuples have a length of 3.